# How to get current date and time in Elasticsearch

Tags: nosql, timezone, elasticsearch

I need to review the current date and time zone from Elasticsearch. I'm checking the elastic documentation and it mentioned that the default value is UTC.

In other environments I use:

```
SELECT NOW();
```

Is there any similar function for Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

According to [these docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-functions-datetime.html#sql-functions-current-timestamp) there's a `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` function and all you need to run is `SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS result;` which will return the current date and time as a timestamp, from the server.

Description from the aforementioned docs:

> Returns the date/time when the current query reached the server. As a function, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() accepts precision as an optional parameter for rounding the second fractional digits (nanoseconds). The default precision is 3, meaning a milliseconds precision current date/time will be returned.